# Help With Basic SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns

> ID, DateStamp

and the ID need not be unique.

How do I write a query that will give me a list of IDs with the minimum DateStamp and the maximum DateStamp?

So, for example, for a given ID, the output may look like:

> 938423, 1/1/2000, 12/13/2003

[I am running SQL Server 2000.]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
SELECT ID, MIN(DateStamp), MAX(DateStamp)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
```

**EDIT** Added from clause for clarity, be sure to change TableName to the actual table name

Comment: Erm, I would, but there is no such button. :/

Comment: @Jake, It's not a button its the big CHECK mark that you should see immediately under the number of votes for the answer. ;-)